# EmberJS: Master-detail, how to bind the detail's model to an item in the master's array model

Tags: ember.js, master-detail

*Disclaimer: I asked a similar question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841178/emberjs-observe-parent-routes-model-and-change-child-routes-model-accordingly), but I am now providing a simpler example along with a jsfiddle.*

I'm trying to set up a master-detail view where model changes only happen on the master route, but I want the detail route to reflect any changes done to its corresponding item in that same model immediately. Currently, I am able see an update only when navigating to another master item and back.

I'm trying to set up a binding to the master controller's model and observe any changes on that from the detail controller.

I have the following templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">
    <h1>People of interest</h1>
    <ul id="master">
        {{#each model}}
        <li>
            <span>{{name}} ({{age}}) {{#link-to 'person' this}}More info{{/link-to}}</span>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <div>
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
    <h2>{{name}}'s items</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

and the following code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('people', {path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('person', {path: ':person_id'});
    });
});

var data = Ember.A([
    Ember.Object.create({id: 1, name: 'Ben', age: 30, items: ['Apple']}),
    Ember.Object.create({id: 2, name: 'Annya', age: 31, items: ['Pencil']})
]);

App.PeopleIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('person', data.findBy('id', 1));
    }
});

App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        Ember.run.later(function() {
            // Issue here. How do I automatically update the detail view to show this change?
            data.replace(0, 1, [Ember.Object.create({id: 1,
                                 name: 'Ben',
                                 age: 30,
                                 items: ['Apple', 'Toy']})]);
            console.log('model changed');
        }, 1000);   
        return data;
    }
});

App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log('person controller init');
    },
    needs: ['people'],
    parentModel: Ember.Binding.oneWay('controllers.people.model'),
    parentModelDidChange: function() { // this never fires
        console.log('parentModel changed');
        // update model here
    }.observes('parentModel')
});
```

I've set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BcTT/8/). In my real application, the data is coming over the wire using *Server Sent Events* with the `EventSource` set up on the master route. The `transitionTo` here is just to make the illustration more practical.

As you can see, the person with id 1 is loaded up front. What I want to happen is while looking tat that person's detail view (`person` route), when that person is updated on the `people` route's model, the `person` controller should somehow know about this, update its own model, and display the changes. None of that happens, though. When the `Ember.run.later` runs, `parentModelDidChange` does not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are observing an array use '@each'. [Here is the working demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zoyiyoje/1/edit). I have added a button which modifies the model in the parent controller. You can click that and see the observer firing by checking the console.

```
parentModelDidChange: function() { // this never fires
    console.log('parentModel changed');
    // update model here
}.observes('parentModel.@each')
```

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for catching that. Also the parentModelBinding property name instead of just parentModel. Thanks a bunch. I have a new jsfiddle with those changes and the actual model update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BcTT/9/).